# Dimension of an Artin $K$-algebra and cardinal of its spectrum

Tags: commutative-algebra, artinian

Let $A$ be an Artin ring that is also a finitely generated $K$-algebra. In particular, the krull dimension of $A$ is $0$. By Noether's Normalisation Lemma we have that $A$ is a $K$-vector space of finite dimension $\dim_{K}A$.

On the other hand, it is known that if $A$ is an Artin ring, $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is finite and discrete.

I was wondering how $\dim_{K}A$ and $\#\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ are related (If there is any relation). For example, does $\#\mathrm{Spec}(A)\leq \dim_{K}A$ hold?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is finitely generated over a field (and commutative!), its nilradical coincides with its Jacobson radical $J$. It follows that $A$ and $A/J$ have the same spectrum. The latter is a commutative semisimple $K$-algebra, so Wedderburn's theorem tells us that it is a direct product of fields, each an  extension of $K$, and its spectrum has one point per factor in this product.

It follows that the number of points in the spectrum is at most the dimension of $A/J$, which itself is at most the dimension of $A$.

Comment: Taking $A=K^n$ we see that we can have equality (and this always happens if $K$ is algbraically closed). On the other hand, taking $A$ to be a finite field extension of $K$ we see that we may also have the other extreme case in which the spectrum has one point. the possibilities in the middle depend on the arithmetic of $K$.

Comment: If $K = \overline K$, one could add that equality holds if and only if $A$ is reduced.